# Are there anatomically good proportions for different dragon-like creatures?

Tags: science-based, anatomy, dragons

I am unsure of what I can add here to make my question more well defined as my question is intended to be general. Answers can vary based on type of dragon-types (Asian vs European) or even (as the title suggests) 'dragon-like' creatures (such as wyverns, drakes, etc.). If there is already a resource for this, I haven't detected it yet; although, I will admit, I've only spent about 24 total hours searching this week prior to asking this question. I am hoping that someone can give me some guidance here.

Thank you for any considerations!

Comment: Of interest: [Anatomically-correct Quetzalcoatl](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/190644/55743), [Sea-serpent evolution into dragon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/236828/55743), [Giant roc and pulse-jet propulsion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/150778/55743) and possible duplicate of: [How could dragons be explained without magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-could-dragons-be-explained-without-magic). Oh, and welcome to Worldbuilding :)

Comment: There are rarely "better" or even "good" proportions in art, especially for anything mythical. I mean, look at how humans are drawn medias, they're often far from having biologically correct proportions. And humans are the thing artists take the most time learning! Yet they are "good" because they have a general art direction. (In Western countries at least) Round creatures are cuter, spiky ones are menacing, and for specific cases like video games it's all about recognizing the outline in a split second (see [Team Fortress 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRzpfMxksA4) for a great example).

Comment: The point is, the choice of a good proportion is up to you. What you want to tell, what you want to convey. It's very unlikely you'll find an objective catch-all better option. And seeing how dragons are depicted very differently... And this is without talking about asian vs western dragons ^^".

Comment: Please let me explain why I closed your question. (a) A LOT of questions [have been asked on this site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+design+dragon) about dragons (that's only a fraction). (b) [Tag:science-based] for a mythical creature is asking a lot. Dragons don't exist. Dragons can't exist. (c) We're willing to help you rationalize your dragon *with specific questions* (see [help/on-topic]) but we're not going to bring your dragon into existence for you. (d) Asking more than one question is a reason to close a question (click "close" read "Needs More Focus").

Answer (score 0):

**Real Creatures**

The good proportions are found by examining real creatures. The Saltwater crocodile is a big lizard with a long head. The Komodo dragon is a moderately big lizard with a short head. A big lizard can believably have a head sized anywhere in between.

Note believable proportions change with size of the animal. Deer legs are dainty. Elephant legs are tree trunks.

Comment: Every time someone calls a crocodilian a "lizard", a cladist cries...  (separation about 280mya)

Comment: @JamesK As you can tell, I am a rebel. I call crocodiles lizards and lizards crocodiles depending on the day of the week. And gosh darn the rest of you.

Comment: Upvote for the saltwater crocodile with deer legs.  You would have gotten 2 upvotes if you included a picture.

Comment: Crocodiles are more closely related to birds (and other dinosaurs) that to lizards. There is very little that crocodiles and lizards have in common which they don't also share with any other random amniote. And, especially for @Willk, [*Silesaurus opolensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silesaurus).